# change this.var in Controller not change in HTML

Tags: angularjs

Please excuse my bad English.

I'm experimenting with controllerAs as Namespace and this instead of $scope

a small example:

```
<html ng-app="MyApp">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="MainController as main">
   <input type="text" ng-model="main.number1" ng-change="main.calculate()"> + 
   <input type="text" ng-model="main.number2" ng-change="main.calculate()">
    <hr>
    <strong>{{main.number1Out}} + {{main.number2Out}} = {{main.result}}</strong>

    <hr>
    Counter: {{main.count}}
  </body>
</html>

angular.module('MyApp', []).

controller('MainController', function () {
  var self = this;

  this.number1 = 0;
  this.number2 = 0;

  this.calculate = function() {
    self.number1Out = parseFloat(self.number1);
    self.number2Out = parseFloat(self.number2);

    self.result = self.number1Out + self.number2Out;
  };
  this.calculate();



  self.count = 1;
  setInterval(function() {
    self.count++;
    console.log('count now: ' + self.count);
  }, 1000);
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/6xfcp7ndaXuZBnnCCrNL?p=preview

the problem in the example:
The change of this.count is only seen in the HTML, if the value of the input fields is changed.

what can I do? (except $scope.$apply() or encapsulate in Directive)

second question:

```
function ControllerOne() {
  this.text = 'Hallo Welt';
}

function ControllerTwo() {
  // is it possible?
  console.log(ControllerOne().text);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the count isn't updated is precisely because you modify the count without calling `$apply()`. So you're doing it "behind the back" of Angular, which has no way to know that the model has changed and that it must reevaluate expressions.

If you don't want to use `$scope.$apply()`, then use the [$interval service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) instead of using setInterval(), so that the service calls `$apply()` for you. Additional benefit: it will be easier to unit-test.

[Updated plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/uaj4Wh7TCBXTNRYVN3GR?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
$interval I wanted to avoid.<br>

http://plnkr.co/edit/mMQF62efCakEo9tH0SaN?p=preview
this.test() every second is called.
I thought I would avoid it because $interval is included in a directive.

Comment: I can say $apply() only in <my-clock></my-clock>?

Comment: Why would you avoid $interval? It does exactly what you want to do. But yes, you can use it in the directive.

Comment: Thanks, I have now found what I was looking for.  
the solution is the parameter invokeApply in $interval and $digest on isoScope  
http://plnkr.co/edit/gQcFYlrDPNVumM2Eect0?p=preview